# How to make token based authentication when someone open a page directly

Tags: javascript, html, http, authentication, jwt

There is a sensitive page in my website, so I want to authenticate visitors before  they opening a link like: www.examples.com/builder.

I know if I use cookie based authentication everything will be simple, as the browser will send the credential message in cookies automatically. But in my situation, I have to use token based authentication. Browser don't send token if there is no pre-load script.

So my question is how to achieve token based authentication when someone open a sensitive page directly.

Comment: What are you using , for example if u are using JWT auth in Laravel , you will have special middleware that will check incoming requests to your endpoints for Bearer token you created. If there is no token,  you will return not authorized header and status to user... Not quite sure if I understood your question correctly. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I am using JWT auth. And I can check incoming requests on server side. My problem is the client side. How does the client side send the Bearer token when it visit the page directly .

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can understand, 
you're looking for a way to **avoid double roundtrips** to send authentication headers to your web-service.

If I am correct, then this would only be possible via `service worker` which is a not widely supported feature. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/

If, depending on your requirements, you can't go for service workers, then, the only left option is to use cookies.

I normally have a secondary authentication flow which uses cookies allowing a web service to authenticate a user on its first get request (the one made by the browser).

There are also some spa framework which implement routing resolvers but this will require a double roundtrip (1. load javascript, 2. send the token).

Comment: This is exactly the answer I am looking for. Is the "double roundtrips" the common way using in authentications?